# Building fiware/cygnus docker from source code - issue with the last step (8)

Tags: image, build, docker, fiware-cygnus

When trying to build a fiware/cygnus docker image from the source code, the last part of it, namely the building of the image from the jar with:

```
docker build -f ./docker/Dockerfile -t fiware/cygnus .
```

gives the following message in the last step (8) of the building process: "no source files were specified". At this point the building appears to be aborted.

The building was done according: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/tree/master/docker (source code from: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus.git ), and basically amounts to first building the java archive (jar) from the provided source code, and subsequently building the docker image from the jar file.

1) What could be the reason for the message in step 8? Since, according to the documentation, no other steps were mentioned. Also, the "target" directory, which is specifically mentioned in the documentation, appears not to be made.

2) However, there does appear an image, but with no tags (*cf* the "-t fiware/cygnus" flag in the command mentioned above). Is this a result from the fact that the building was only done up to step 8, leaving an incomplete image?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi. 1st question: Did you check that there is a `.jar` file in the `target` directory? i.e. cygnus-0.11.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: If not, probably is an error with the `Dockerfiles` which are using an outdated version of `Java 1.7.0`. Please, implement the following changes in your image contained in this PR https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/pull/695/files, until we merge them :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 8 is

```
Step 8 : ADD ./target/*.jar /tmp/
```

This means that probably you haven't had success building the `jar`.

Replicating the steps with the current HEAD `2a9c87fb7fd6156225e2eed7fbc9792f1d9c5dfe` gave me some errors, attributed to the `JAVA_HOME` variable not properly set.

Please, implement the following changes in your `Dockerfiles` until we merge the into master:

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/pull/695/files

Comment: Cheers mate, this solved the problem. As for 1), after the changes were implemented in the two docker files (as per your link), the building of the jar and image worked fine. The "target" directory is now also created. As for 2), the tags were also added to the image.